# Divide to numbers but keep decimal?

Tags: velocity

How to divide two numbers but keep the decimal point.

Also I need to turn the decimal point into a percentage...ie .25 to 25%

tried $set ($percent = $a / $b)
In this case $a = 10, $b = 40.

```
#set($percent = $totalSponsored / $totalAppliesAllJobs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered this using:

## set($percent = $a * 100 / $b)

Answer (score -1):

`double result = (double) number1 / (double) number2 * 100.0`

The `result` variable now contains the percentage.

Comment: That is the whole percentage, not only the remainder. `1.25` will become `125%` though I'm not sure what OP wants.

Comment: It's the best I could do. It was't really clear from his question if it was intended. I'm not even sure if OP is actually using Java, considering the variables start with a `$`

Comment: I'm using velocity, java templating language. I removed the java tag.